# Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement' for audio seeking

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slider on html

```
<div class="duration">
       <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="duration_slider" onchange="change_duration()">
</div>
```

So this is a part of my audio player and on changing the slider, it is supposed to change the duration of the song.
I have taken audio input from html

```
<audio id = "mysong">
   <source src = "{{song.song.url}}" type = "audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

And my code for the javascript are

```
let slider = document.querySelector('#duration_slider');
var mysong = document.getElementById('mysong');

//to change the duration of my song.
function change_duration(){
     slider_position = mysong.duration * (mysong.value / 100);
     mysong.currentTime = slider_position;
}
//to update the slider a/c to my song duration.
function range_slider(){
    let position = 0;
        if(!isNaN(mysong.duration)){
           position = mysong.currentTime * (100 / mysong.duration);
           slider.value =  position;
          }     
}
```

But I got an error saying
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite. at change_duration ((index):122) at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):75). The slider is updating but change_duration() function is not working, meanwhile on same concept my volume slider changes.

Comment: Where are you loading the audio from? Is that a live stream?

Comment: I'm loading the audio from django, it loads and plays, my only problem is it doesn't seek. I believe my concept if right but my change_duration() might be mistake or sth @Tushar

Comment: What do you want to retrieve using mysong.value. That is probably undefined. Did you do console.log(mysong.value).

Comment: Yes, it gives me undefined for some reason.
I have also tried ```let slider_position = slider.value;```
      ```mysong.currentTime = slider_position;```
      ```console.log(slider_position);``` which gives me the required value, but doen't updates it

Comment: You tried this : `let slider_position = slider.value; mysong.currentTime = slider_position * (mysong.duration / 100); console.log(slider_position);`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is mysong.currentTime is not changing. @Tushar

Comment: Ok. Please as you are debugging add console.log values to the comments/question. What is console.log(slider_position * (mysong.duration / 100));. What is console.log(mysong.duration)?

Comment: well it depends on how much i slide the slider. For eg when i move to value 15 of the range input, the values are 39.3952653, 128 262.635102 respectively

Comment: So values are correct. Getting any error or nothing is happening?

Comment: I don't get any errors now after trying what you said, but when i change the slider its supposed to start the song from there but it restarts. I have changed ```mysong.currentTime = slider_position * (mysong.duration / 100);``` But if i console.log(mysong.currentTime) its 0 (It starts from beginning) @Tushar

Comment: Ok. I don't know if this might help but instead of your <source> can you add  `src = "{{song.song.url}}" type = "audio/mp3">` to the audio tag itself. That is one more way to add src.